# Inherit flags from "main" SE sites

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, flagging

On SO and SU, there is an off-topic flag specifically for marking questions which ask for product or service recommendations.

(Directly from SO)

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

So why does Sports SE *not* have one of its own? There are questions [like this one](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13200/question-regarding-price) and [this one](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/books-about-umpiring-officiating-in-sports) which do nothing but ask whether this product is right for them, or whether or not this is a reliable source.

---

I suggest:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find equipment, rules of the game, guides or other off-site resources** are off-topic for Sports SE as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.  Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

> So why does Sports SE not have [a flag specifically for marking questions which ask for product or service recommendations.]?

With my limited observation, I claim status by design. Below are the off-topic reasons found on SO (which includes the product recommendation verbiage you quote).

[image: SO close reasons]

---

For Sports SE, we have default close reason...:

> This question does not appear to be about sports within the scope defined in the help center.

...and three custom close reasons (two of which are currently "active"):

> General health and medical advice is off-topic here; you should contact a qualified medical professional instead.
>
> Questions on exercise and fitness unrelated to a specific, competitive sport are off-topic here, but can be asked on Physical Fitness Stack Exchange.

Other (currently "inactive") close reasons:

> Requests for **sources and/or research** are off-topic.  For more information, see [the help center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
>
> Questions on **outdoor** activities unrelated to a specific, competitive sport are off-topic here, but can be asked on [The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com).